# Spark Maximum temperature example by definitive guide

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and I tried to execute the program max temperature from Hadoop definitive guide but it is throwing error array out of bound exception in last. And I am not able to understand clearly the code which is in the book.

Below is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object MaxTemperature {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Max Temperature").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val lines = sc.textFile("011990-99999-1949.txt")
val records = lines.map(_.split("\t"))
val filtered = records.filter(rec => (rec(1) != "9999"
&& rec(2).matches("[01459]")))
val tuples = filtered.map(rec => (rec(0).toInt, rec(1).toInt))
val maxTemps = tuples.reduceByKey((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
maxTemps.foreach(println(_))
}
}
```

I am getting the point only that they are reading the file and after that split and map function I am not getting tried to break down the split and map function to different RDD but not got useful things can anyone suggest me how to check the output for each steps.

Thanks & Regards
Amit

Comment: Which line gives the exception? Also, since there are explicit indices, used for `rec` you're relying on the format of the input file and every line having at least 3 enties - so can you say what that looks like?

Comment: The problem is with the formatting of input text file. There shouldn't be any empty lines and also every line should have 3 or more tab separated variable.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to process these lines of the file but there is no \t present in the line and i ma not sure where i have to split the line by tab so that i can get the desire result. 0067011990999991949010107004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0201801N006719999999N9999999N9-00281+99999999999ADDAA199000591AY131999GF108991999999999999999999KA1999N-01001MW1101
0043011990999991949010112004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0201801N006719999999N9999999N9-00281+99999999999ADDAY131999GF108991999999999999999999MW1361

Comment: Can anyone comment on this please ..

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code may be it can help :-

Sample input:- 
91  67  Agra    Uttar Pradesh   33  19
90  67  Allahabad   Uttar Pradesh   32  19
87  60  Amritsar    Punjab  30  15
89  66  Bhopal  Madhya Pradesh  32  19
87  62  Chandigarh  Chandigarh  30  17
82  60  Dehradun    Uttarakhand 28  15
89  64  Indore  Madhya Pradesh  32  18
89  65  Lucknow Uttar Pradesh   40  18

Objective: - find maximum temperature of particular state

Here comes our program:-

```
import org.apache.spark._;

object testfilter extends App {
  val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("testfilter")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c://winutil//")
  val input=sc.textFile("file:///D://sparkprog//temp//stats.txt")
  val line=input.map(x=>x.split("\t"))
  val city=line.map(x=>(x(3)+"\t" + x(4)))
  val rdd3=city.map(x=>x.split("\t"))
  val maintemp=rdd3.map(x=>((x(0),x(1))))
  val grp= maintemp.groupByKey()
  val main = grp.map{case (x,iter) => (x,iter.toList.max)}


  for ( i<- main)
  {
    print(i)
    print("\n")
  }

}
```

Run the above program and we will get output like:- 
(Jammu and Kashmir,20)(Madhya Pradesh,32)

(Bihar,31) and so on ..

important :- i
nputs are tab separated